# pgAdmin launches pg_restore with invalid database name

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

New install of PostgreSQL and pgAdmin on Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit.

On restoring a database schema with pgAdmin, it launches the following command:

```
/usr/bin/pg_restore --host opusdb --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname \"mydb\" --verbose "mydb.backup"
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database ""mydb"" failed: FATAL:  database ""mydb"" does not exist
pg_restore: *** aborted because of error

Process returned exit code 1.
```

The problem is due to the \" before and after the database name. The following works on the command line (note the absent \ characters):

```
/usr/bin/pg_restore --host opusdb --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname "mydb" --verbose "mydb.backup"
```

Not sure if pgAdmin is suddenly using a different syntax, or pg_restore doesn't understand the \" anymore. Could it be in any way related to the 64-bit installation of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this is a problem with the particular pgadmin3 version: [osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2011-05/msg30089.html](http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2011-05/msg30089.html)

The next version shouldn't have this problem anymore.